# How to properly copy dynamic content in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

The code below was designed to copy dynamic content (name data) to a clipboard when a certain button is click.

My issue is that only the last name get copied irrespective of the button that was clicked. Eg. If click to copy name **Tony** which is the first data in the array, it will copy **Tom** which is the last data in the JSON result and successful message will be wrongly showed in all rows.

Below is the screenshots

[image: screenshots]

Is a workaround available?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>

<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { id: 1,name: "Tony", Age: "18", gender: "male" },
        { id: 2,name: "John", Age: "21", gender: "female" },
        { id: 3,name: "Luke", Age: "78", gender: "male" },
        { id: 4,name: "tom", Age: "89", gender: "female" }
      ],
copyName: ''
    };


    this.clickToCopy = this.clickToCopy.bind(this);

  }

   clickToCopy(e){
//clickToCopy(e,id){
    this.textArea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    e.target.focus();
    this.setState({ copyName: 'This name has been Copied successfully' });

/*
// ensure that only the selected button will triger copied successfully
    const success = this.state.rec.filter(i => i.id !== id)
    this.setState({ copyName: 'This name has been Copied successfully' });
*/
  };



  render() {


    return (
      <div>

        <div>
          <h3> Records</h3>
          

          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.id} {obj.name} - {obj.Age} - {obj.gender}

<div>
        {
         document.queryCommandSupported('copy') &&
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.clickToCopy}>Copy This Name</button> 
            {this.state.copyName}
          </div>
        }
        <form>
          <textarea
            ref={(textarea) => this.textArea = textarea}
            value={obj.name}
          />
        </form>
      </div>


              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));


</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give each textarea a different ref, and onClick copy button select and execute copy.

```
<textarea
  ref={input => {
   this[`textArea-${i}`] = input;
  }}
  ...
/>

clickToCopy = (e, id) => {
  this[`textArea-${id}`].select(); // select textarea below clicked button

  document.execCommand("copy");

  this.setState({
    copyId: id // save id of the clicked button
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18", gender: "male" },
        { id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21", gender: "female" },
        { id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78", gender: "male" },
        { id: 4, name: "tom", Age: "89", gender: "female" }
      ],
      copyName: "This name has been Copied successfully",
      copyId: "",
      copied: ""
    };
  }

  clickToCopy = (e, id) => {
    this[`textArea-${id}`].select();

    document.execCommand("copy");

    this.setState({
      copyId: id
    });
  };

  paste = () => {
    navigator.clipboard
      .readText()
      .then(clipText => this.setState({ copied: clipText }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3> Records</h3>

          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.id} {obj.name} - {obj.Age} - {obj.gender}
                <div>
                  {document.queryCommandSupported("copy") && (
                    <div>
                      <button onClick={e => this.clickToCopy(e, i)}>
                        Copy This Name
                      </button>
                      {this.state.copyId === i && this.state.copyName}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <form>
                    <textarea
                      ref={input => {
                        this[`textArea-${i}`] = input;
                      }}
                      value={obj.name}
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.paste}>Paste</button>
        {this.state.copied && <p>Copied Text: {this.state.copied}</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is by creating a `refs` object with each key set as the `id` of the object. When you are doing the map, you can assign the textarea ref to the `obj.id` of the `refs` object.

What I will do instead is giving each button a `name` attribute of the `obj.id`, then in your `clickToCopy` function, I will use `e.target.name` to get the `id` of the obj, and use that to `select` your textarea.

I would also save the last copied `obj.id` into state, and do rendering based on the `copiedID` and the `obj.id`.

I've also updated to use the `obj.id` as the `<li>`'s key.

You can take a look at the example code below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18", gender: "male" },
        { id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21", gender: "female" },
        { id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78", gender: "male" },
        { id: 4, name: "tom", Age: "89", gender: "female" }
      ],
      copiedID: ""
    };
    // setup textareaRefs
    const { rec } = this.state;
    this.textareaRefs =
      Array.isArray(rec) && rec.length > 0
        ? rec.reduce((res, item) => {
            res[item.id] = React.createRef();
            return res;
          }, {})
        : {};
    this.clickToCopy = this.clickToCopy.bind(this);
  }

  clickToCopy(e) {
    this.textareaRefs[e.target.name].current.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    this.setState({ copiedID: e.target.name });
  }

  render() {
    const { rec, copiedID } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Records</h3>
          <ul>
            {rec.map(obj => (
              <li key={obj.id}>
                {obj.id} {obj.name} - {obj.Age} - {obj.gender}
                <div>
                  {document.queryCommandSupported("copy") && (
                    <div>
                      <button name={obj.id} onClick={this.clickToCopy}>
                        Copy This Name
                      </button>
                      {copiedID === `${obj.id}` ? "This name has been Copied successfully" : null}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <form>
                    <textarea
                      ref={this.textareaRefs[obj.id]}
                      value={obj.name}
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot @dev_junwen. am upvoting now as this really make sense also